# DNS server merging

Tags: vpn, dns, merge, dnsmasq

I have a router running, among other things, `dnsmasq` with standard setup, so I get DNS proxy plus additional local servers, plus name resolution for all machines whose IP address is managed via `dnsmasq` DHCP server.

Servers and other hosts are on my `home.net` domain

So far so good.

Now I need to connect via VPN to a customer site (`customer.net`) who has a very similar setup (they are not using dnsmasq, but net effect is the same).

I set up a small (virtual) machine acting as router forwarding (with NAT) from local network to IPSec `tun` device and added a few static routes to the (2) hosts needing to see customer.net; I did this manually instead of pushing the routes through dnsmasq.

Also this seems to work without problems.

Now I have the last problem I don't know how to solve:

I can access machines in `customer.net` private address space only specifying the IP address, no DNS resolution is available from `dns.customer.net`

How can I access `dns.customer.net` *without* losing connection with `dns.home.net`?

**NOTE**: I can modify my `home.net` setup (I would prefer to limit changes to the few hosts actually involved), but I have no control on `customer.net`

Situation I would like to have is:

- `*.home.net` addresses should be resolved by `dnsmasq`
- Internet routable addresses should be resolved by `dnsmasq` proxying my ISP DNS.
- `*.customer.net` addresses should be resolved by `dns.customer.net` (I can access this host via its non-routable IP), possibly without going through my `dnsmasq`

Is this at all possible? If so, how?

Comment: add a record to dnsmasq for dns.customer.net ? You can spoof DNS entries via dnsmasq.... https://blog.heckel.xyz/2013/07/18/how-to-dns-spoofing-with-a-simple-dns-server-using-dnsmasq/#Add-forged-DNS-entries

Comment: @djsmiley2k: evidently I was not clear enough. Adding a single (or a few) specific entries to dnsmasq hosts file is no problem. I would like to be able to resolve *all* entries for which dns.customer.net is authoritative thus effectively "merging" two independent DNS servers (dnsmasq at dns.home.net + bind at dns.customer.net)

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109115/9583, which references https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22555/9583 for the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I found out `dnsmasq` can do what I need.

Here comes an excerpt from standard documentation ([Dnsmasq setup](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html)):

> Using special servers.
>
> Dnsmasq has the ability to direct DNS queries for certain domains to specific upstream nameservers. This feature was added for use with VPNs but it is fully general. The scenario is this: you have a standard internet connection via an ISP, and dnsmasq is configured to forward queries to the ISP's nameservers, then you make a VPN connection into your companies network, giving access to hosts inside the company firewall. You have access, but since many of the internal hosts aren't visible on the public internet, your company doesn't publish them to the public DNS and you can't get their IP address from the ISP nameservers. The solution is to use the companies nameserver for private domains within the company, and dnsmasq allows this. Assuming that internal company machines are all in the domain internal.myco.com and the companies nameserver is at 192.168.10.1 then the option server=/internal.myco.com/192.168.10.1 will direct all queries in the internal domain to the correct nameserver. You can specify more than one domain in each server option. If there is more than one nameserver just include as many server options as is needed to specify them all.

In the end I added both DNS "special server" and additional static routes to my main dnsmasq (on my firewall) and everything works as needed as soon as the VPN Virtual Machine is up-and-running.

Actual lines added to my dnsmasq.conf are:

```
server=/customer.net/192.168.20.253
dhcp-option=121,192.168.2.0/24,192.168.7.11,192.168.20.0/24,192.168.7.11
```

I hope this helps someone to cut the chase.